# RHEL 6.5 how to disable cd/dvd burning for users

Tags: rhel-6

I have a need to disable CD/DVD burning for users on a RHEL6 machine. I still need to use the optical drive for mounting read-only discs to import data. I just need to make it so users can't write data on the machine to CD/DVD.

I found an article on redhat.com that said to do the following in /etc/fstab but it didn't work:

```
/dev/cdrom      /media/dvdrecorder     iso9660 ro,user,noauto,unhide 0 0
```

Anyone have a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an older post that advises restricting the access of ''/usr/bin/cdrecord'', because it is the binary used from all cd burning apps (or so it was a decade ago).

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/disabling-cd-burner-write-access-363576/

Comment: I also restricted access to /usr/bin/wodim and /usr/bin/brasero

Comment: Did restricting the access to the three binaries solve the issue?

Comment: It appears that it has. By doing a chmod o-x on each binary a general user cannot run Brasero anymore. Unless I'm overlooking a way to write data to a CD/DVD then I think this worked. I don't think you can do this with dd? Someone let me know if I'm overlooking a method that could be used for burning CD/DVDs.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting brasero, wodim, and genisofs did not help me. As Nautilus appears to have burning capability built-in. Restricting Nautilus kills a lot of Gnome's functionality. Figuring out how RHEL 6.5 assigns ACLs to /dev/sr0 seems to be the key, and udev and dbus are not providing any clues to how, but seem to be responsible.